# Scrolling element with filter: blur skips in latest firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, performance, firefox

### Background

Firefox 58.0.2 (64-bit) (latest version as of 3/9/2018)

An element with a background blur in front of a background image skips and makes sudden movements on scrolling in the latest Firefox:

[Here's an example (try scrolling up and down in latest Firefox)](https://lnfwebsite.github.io/Streamly/#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)

This behavior cannot be repeated in Chrome and did not exist in Firefox versions prior to the [Quantum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_(Mozilla)) release. I'm thinking that the quantum release brought faster rendering for better CPU performance and is only re-rendering on the end of the scroll event... or something...

### Question(s)

Is this a bug in Firefox?

How can I prevent this behavior in the meantime?

Comment: Blur has many bugs in various implementations and is currently heavy on CPU usage. I suggest you find another way to archive this design. You could use a half milky transparent png. It won't be the same as the blur effect but it will certainly perform faster

Answer (score 0):

Promoting the layer to the GPU to enable hardware acceleration seems to work. You can use the `will-change` property for this.

```
#blurBackground {
  will-change: transform;
}
```

Comment: Hi, the `will-change` property seems to extend the background across the `#blurBackground` div and does not appear stand still during scrolling as it is supposed to.